# Could not open locked file when trying to install with apt-get

Tags: apt, packages

Now, here is my question:

Who hates apt-get? Almost no one. Who gets problems with apt-get? I do. And I am.

Sometimes, using `sudo apt-get upgrade` takes sooooo long you just close off terminal to stop the "upgrade".

Oh well. Tried that, and now I'm getting problems when trying to install something else. For example, `sudo apt-get update` or `sudo apt-get mesa-utils`(A graphics library) didn't work. `sudo apt-get upgrade` didn't work at all, either, when I tried to try the upgrade again. I even went to the Raspberry Pi config (`sudo raspi-config`) and tried the update thing there (advanced options -> update), but they all outputted this or similar error messages.

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

And yes, these errors popped up right after or during update/upgrade/installing time, and, as you can see, I was using the `sudo`'s right.

What do these errors mean? How can they be fixed? And if you say I have to reinstall Raspbian all over again, weeeeell. Yeah.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the upgrade process still has locked the applications and the process might still be running in the background or glitched, try rebooting and then install a new version of raspbian, might save the update time.

Comment: Thanks Enan. Reinstalling Raspbian solved all my problems, though I have to criticize you for making me lose all my data. Anyway, I'm way more gratefull than I am mad.